# How can I implement a Next.js Image component with a fixed width and dynamic height to keep the image's dimensions?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, sanity

The image is sourced from SanityCMS, and the current code (ChakraUI styling) I have is:

```
<Box w="500px" h="500px" bg="red">
  <Image
    src={allArtPieces[0].imageUrl}
    alt={allArtPieces[0].title}
    width="500px"
    height="500px"
  />
</Box>
```

I would like to have the width of the image fill the container and the image to keep its natural dimensions. I have already tried setting the width of the image to 100% and leaving out the height style prop, however, the Next Image component requires that I declare a height variable. Any ideas on how I can achieve the functionality I'm aiming for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep width as 100% as you said or from `API` and also for height use the value of height of the image from `API` given by `SanityCMS` to keep the natural dimensions of your image.

Log the result of `allArtPieces[0]` in console and there should be the value of height of your image.